# Verbatim strings in PureScript

Tags: purescript

Does PureScript support verbatim string literals? Something like `@"regex \s no escapes"` in C#.

Alternatively is there support for regex literals as in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [triple-quote strings](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/language/Syntax.md#triple-quote-strings).

There are no regex literals AFAIK, but triple-quote strings might help there too. Example from docs:

```
regex """.+@.+\..+""" noFlags
```